# Solve differential equation $f'(x)+f^2(x)=4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $f'(x)+f^2(x)=4\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, finding all such functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

I have a feeling that the solution is $f(x)=2$ and $f(x)=-2$, but don't know how to prove that f is constant. We can, however, conclude that $f'(x)\leq 4,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Any hint?

Comment: Am I interpreting this wrong? $f(x)=2$ $\implies$ $f^'(x)=0$ and $f^2(x)=0$  or does your notation mean something different?

Comment: The two solutions $2$ and $-2$ are only solutions to the equilibrium equation. This is a separable differential equation

Comment: It is a [Riccati equation][1].  


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equationI

Comment: @Dan What is an equilibrium equation?

Comment: It applies to DE where derivative terms vanish

Comment: @123, if $f(x)=2$ then $f^2(x) = 4$.  Perhaps you're thinking of the second derivative, which can be denoted $f''(x)$ or $f^{(2)}(x)$, but not $f^2(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a casual first observation, first note your ODE is
$$f'=G(f),$$
where $G(t)=4-t^{2}$.  Since $G$ is only locally Lipschitz, global solutions may not exist (they could blow up in finite time).  Therefore, there may be no solution at all which is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

As it turns out, there are *some* solutions which are stable and exist globally on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., certain initial conditions will yield global solutions.  However, some initial conditions will lead to solutions which blow-up in finite time and are therefore defined only locally (there are no issues to local existence/uniqueness, however, since $G$ is nevertheless locally Lipschitz).  If you're familiar with the methods, you can see this by analyzing the fixed points of $G$ at $t=\pm2$.

You can solve this using elementary ODE solution methods (in particular, separation of variables):

$$\frac{df}{dx}=4-f^{2}$$
$$\int\frac{df}{4-f^{2}}=\int\;dx$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\log\left(\frac{f+2}{2-f}\right)=x+C$$
where $C\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant.  Solving for $f$, we obtain
$$f=f(x)=\frac{2(e^{4(x+C)}-1)}{e^{4(x+C)}+1}$$
or simplifying further
$$f=f(x)=\frac{2(e^{4x}-e^{4C})}{e^{4x}+e^{4C}}.$$

Note that this solution is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $f(0)\geq-2$.  For example, if $f(0)=-3$, then we obtain a solution that blows up as soon as $x=5e^{-4}$.

**Edit:** The explicit solution formula above is valid only when $f(0)\geq-2$; when $f(0)<-2$, then the implicit solution is
$$\frac{1}{4}\log\left(\frac{f+2}{f-2}\right)=x+C,$$
leading to the explicit solution
$$f=f(x)=\frac{2(e^{4x}+e^{4C})}{e^{4x}-e^{4C}},$$
which shows that solutions blow-up in finite time for such initial conditions.  This is all because one has to be careful of the domain when integrating the function $\frac{1}{x}$; the anti-derivative is $\log|x|$, which is equal to $\log(x)$ when $x\geq0$ and $\log(-x)$ when $x<0$.

Comment: I really don't understand how you arrived to the constraint of f... Can you explain that a bit more, please? Also, I don't know anything about Lipschitz...

Comment: It can be seen in more detail from niemanski's answer.  I also included an edit so you can see it from the analytical point of view.  You don't need to worry about what Lipschitz means if you haven't studied it yet (it's a stronger form of continuity, and in the theory of ODE, it is a sufficient condition to ensure existence/uniqueness of solutions, at least locally).

Answer (score 8):

That can be written as:
$$ \frac{f'(x)}{4-f(x)^2} = 1 $$
and since $\int\frac{dt}{4-t^2} = C+\frac{1}{4}\log\left(\frac{2+t}{2-t}\right)$ we get:
$$ \log\left(\frac{2+f(t)}{2-f(t)}\right) = 4t-C $$
so:
$$ f(t) = 2\frac{K e^{4t}-1}{K e^{4t}+1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The problem is separable. Rearranging gives $$\frac{f'(x)}{4- f^2(x)} = 1 \,\,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\,\, \frac{f'(x)}{(2+f(x))(2-f(x))} = 1.$$ Now use partial fractions and integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in this case one should at first give a qualitative analysis on it.
We have $f'(x)=4-f(x)^2$, as we see we have for $0=4-y^2$ which implies $y= \pm 2$ thus if the initial values $y_0= \pm 2$ the solution will be constant ($\pm 2)$.
Now let the intial value $y_0>2$ then we have $4-y^2<0$ which implies the solution will converge to 2. If we starting at $y_0 \in (-2,2)$ we have $4-y_0^2>0$ which implies the solution will converge to $2$. And having $y_0<-2$ we have $4-y_0^2<0$ and the solution will converge to $- \infty$.

Comment: Great analysis!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are right in the $f'(x)\leq 4$; however, the solution is not so simple.

By separation, we can arrive at the following integral

$\int\dfrac{1}{4-y^2}dy=\int dx$

By partial fractions, we have

$\int\dfrac{1}{(y-2)(y+2)}dy=x$

This leads us to $\ln|\dfrac{y+2}{2-y}|=4x$

Solving this through leads to $y=\dfrac{2(Ce^{4x}-1)}{Ce^{4x}+1}$

There is still a lot to be shown in these intermediary steps.